# Xcode - No outlets showing up

Tags: ios, xcode

Suddenly outlets from the .m files stopped showing up in Xcode. I have multiple View Controllers in my storyboard. Each View Controller has its own ViewController.h and .m file with its own name. Previously it has worked out great and I could see the outlets from the .m file and link it to objects. But now only outlets from the .h file show up in the storyboard. The class is of course entered in the "custom class" text area.

The code that worked previously is the exact same that I copied over to the other files but changed the names accordingly.

(**The code is objective-c and my xcode version is 7.0**)

I've tried:

- Creating new [NAME].m and [NAME].h files.
- Creating new View Controllers and attaching the class to it.
- Re-written the code after suggestions online and also checked so everything needed is in the code.

If you need any screenshots or code, just let me know and I'll do my best.

Comment: Can you post your .h and .m ?

Comment: @MidhunMP 
Here's the .h file: http://pastebin.com/TRCkD1J1
Here's the .m file: http://pastebin.com/KCPCFJSg